# How to reference cell (sum function) in another worksheet and display as value

Tags: excel

There are multiple worksheets in my workbook. One worksheet named 'Region 1' contains a formula in cell B17, =Sum(B3:B16). I'd like a formula to put in a different worksheet named 'Order Regions', cell B9, that displays the value of cell B17 in 'Region 1'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"Name" the cell in the worksheet "Region 1" ... call it "Region_1_Sum" or something.

In Order Regions, cell B9 put:

```
=Region_1_Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly just reference the cell with

```
='Region 1'!B17
```

?

Comment: That works, as well. Not sure why, but when I tried this earlier it displayed the formula and not the value. But it's working now! thanks.